# Windows 7 taskbar, create popup menus?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Is there a way in Windows 7 to create a single icon that pops up with a menu? I'm used to having [True Launch Bar](http://www.truelaunchbar.com) installed, but at the moment it doesn't integrate with the new taskbar/shortcut bar of Windows 7, so I'm missing it.

Basically, I'd like to pin a single icon on the shortcut bar, and when clicked, pops up a menu that contains, as an example, all my games, or all my development tools, instead of pinning them all to the shortcut as individual icons.

It doesn't have to be built into Windows 7 either, so if there's 3rd party solutions available, please point me to them as well.

Note that I know that TLB is compatible with Windows 7 in the sense that I can install and enable the TLB launchbar, but it is separate from the Windows 7 taskbar, in the sense that only integrates a XP/Vista style quick launch bar into the taskbar. What I'd like is to mix popup-icons into the taskbar, among the other normally pinned applications.

Comment: There is a Windows-native way to do it, which takes a folder with shortcuts or another folders. It will expand on click. No need to install or set anything. Just take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want to get is [Jumplist Launcher](http://en.www.ali.dj/jumplist-launcher/). It lets you add shortcuts into the program's jumplist so you always have them available and don't have to fill your taskbar with 20 different shortcuts.

[image]

Comment: It only allows to select one app per folder. :(

Answer (score 9):

There actually is a **Windows native** solution to this. And it's also working in **Windows 10**.

I use custom menus since Windows XP (quick launch), but the current quick launch isn't friendly with subfolders. In Windows 7+ you use **Links** instead:

[image]

---

- Right-click windows taskbar -> **Toolbars** -> enable **Links**

  [image]
- Then you have to open the Links folder, it should be located somewhere here

  ```
  %USERPROFILE%\Favorites\
  ```

  *(the best way is to create a folder in the newly added Links menu and then right-click and open that folder)*
- Fill your folders with shortcuts, another folders, executables, songs, movies, ... whatever
  You can create as many folders as you want, you can then choose which and how many of them will be shown on your taskbar (by drag'n'drop). You can also change default icons for them.
- Unlock the taskbar, resize the area and rearrange what icons you want to see. I recommend disabling `Show Text` and `Show title`. Then lock the taskbar again to hide the resizer.
  [image]

The only drawback to this is that some programs (don't know why not all) which you start from that menu will first show a popup alert if you are aware that this program can hurt your computer as this is Links folder, which was dedicated to web-related content first. *(*workaround below)*

The advantage of this solution is that if you create custom toolbar using other tools, you can't use those shiny custom icons for popup menus.

---

**EDIT:**
There is a workaround to disable those annoying alerts, though I recommend it only to experienced users and to those who know what they are doing with their PC as this will lessen windows security. **note that this is available only on Pro editions.*

In the start menu enter `gpedit.msc`. Then go to `User Configuration` -> `Administrative Templates` -> `Windows Components` -> `Attachment Manager` and Add "`;.exe;.lnk`" to the "`Inclusion list for low risk file types`" setting.

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: Forgot - had to search internet - found this again.  Still a great answer

Comment: @user1167442 Thanks! This is funny, I use my answer myself from time to time :)

Comment: Hi me from three and six years ago.  We have returned.

Comment: @dgo Careful, people might start seeing patterns! 
_PS: 3 years sounds like a reasonable Windows lifecycle _

Comment: Hey, thanks again, past @Qwerty, what an amazing answer!

Answer (score 4):

7stacks might be what you seek.

[7stacks](http://www.alastria.com/index.php?p=software-7s)

use it and love it. :)

Comment: Maybe. What does it do? How is it relevant to the question? [Please do not post answers that consist of just a link.](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Comment: Seems to be similar to [the accepted one](http://superuser.com/a/23399/35237), though their homepage is badly outdated, you can't even browse the screenshots link correctly...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of the steps off hand, but have you tried creating a new folder toolbar? If you right click the Taskbar, and select Toolbars, by default there is one for the desktop (so you can activate that to see how it would work). I think that there is an option on that popup menu to create a new toolbar for an arbitrary folder. So, you could create a folder that contains all of the shortcuts to all of your games, and then you'd have access to those shortcuts from the taskbar.

See [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/9542-custom-toolbars.html) for the complete list of steps (near the bottom of the page).

Comment: Yeah, I've experimented with that, but it's not quite what I want. What it does is add a normal toolbar with icons on it, and it only shows the name of the toolbar, not an icon. The only way to make it a popup is to size it small enough to get the chevron. Close, but not quite.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably try building such a program yourself which will have a custom Jump List. You would then just right-click on the icon for that to work.

Would certainly be possible that way but involves some coding. Altough the .NET APIs for the new taskbar are pretty nice.

Comment: Oooh, that sounds promising, and fun to boot, I remember seeing a api drop the other day for Windows 7 as well, I'll look at that first.

Comment: Yeah, this one: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, both 7stacks and Jumplists are useless, you can do this with LINKS and custom toolbars. In order to have a configuration like:

StartMenu-AppStack1-AppStack2-QuickLaunch-OpenAppTabs

do the following:

- create a new toolbar in the taskbar, put in the folder whatever links you need. Then drag this new toolbar in the left side, this will be the quick launch toolbar.
- enable "Links" toolbar in the taskbar and drag it in the left side, near start button. Unlike the other toolbars, links will be seen as menus, just fill the folders inside with other folders or shortcuts.
  You have to disable texts and titles accordingly, also resize icons if necessary. It will be even better then XP.

A medium person has about 50-100 application installed.....each one should be reached in maximum 2 clicks, this can be done best by stacked links near start menu.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new folder toolbar and then docking it all the way at the right. That way it won't show any icons until you press the >> button to show the popup menu. Sometimes the toolbar size gets messed up after you lock it again, but you can use [this trick](https://superuser.com/questions/242/how-do-i-lock-right-aligned-toolbars-in-win7-without-them-looking-awful) to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/plerup/LaunchBar

get the setup from the author website.

"Please note that as opposed to the original QuickLaunch toolbar, the LaunchBar toolbar window cannot be manually resized, only positioned. It will always just be one button wide/high and adjusted to the number of buttons present."

Comment: Not ideal, but worked for me better that any other option suggested here.

Answer (score 0):

I tried few apps trying to do that. Now I'm using [Free lunch bar](http://www.freelaunchbar.com/). This the best what I find.

Comment: The last version is from 2009, and the title picture shows Windows XP -- this makes me think it may be too old in Windows 10 times.